# What is a succinct way to write a coffeescript function that converts my json array into the format that I want

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have this json object:

```
  op = [{"id":7,"d_set_id":1,"option_value_id":5,"product_id":3,"model":"1300","option_type":"Plunger Diameter","option":"5.0 inch Plunger Diameter","product":"Packing","route":"part_option_values","reqParams":null,"restangularized":true,"fromServer":true,"parentResource":{"route":"parts","parentResource":null,"id":"29"},"restangularCollection":false},{"id":9,"d_set_id":5,"option_value_id":11,"product_id":3,"model":"1300","option_type":"main drum diameter","option":"1.0  main drum diameter","product":"Packing","route":"part_option_values","reqParams":null,"restangularized":true,"fromServer":true,"parentResource":{"route":"parts","parentResource":null,"id":"29"},"restangularCollection":false}]
```

I wrote this function to convert it to the format that I want:

```
addItems: (op) ->
   variant = { 
    product_id: "undefined"
    model: "undefined"
    options: []
    product: "undefinded"
    option_value_ids: []
    quantity: 1
  }   
  op.forEach (obj,i) ->
    variant.product_id = obj.product_id
    variant.model = obj.model
    variant.options.push obj.option
    variant.product = obj.product
    variant.option_value_ids.push obj.option_value_id
  variant.options = variant.options.join(', ')
  items.push variant
```

It successfully changes it into my desired result.

```
  items = [{"product_id":3,"model":"1300","options":"5.0 inch Plunger Diameter, 1.0  main drum diameter","product":"Packing","option_value_ids":[5,11],"quantity":1},{"product_id":3,"model":"1300","options":"5.0 inch Plunger Diameter, 1.0  main drum diameter","product":"Packing","option_value_ids":[5,11],"quantity":1}]
```

... but this doesn't seem like a very succinct way to write this function.  What is a better way?

Comment: OK, I've not done any CoffeeScript but can't you omit the initial declaration of `variant`? I imagine you should be able to and then just create _and_ define all properties _and_ add it to the `items` array all inside the `forEach` loop. That would cut the code roughly in half.

Comment: For performance, fyi, I'd avoid forEach, and use "for key, obj in op", instead. And do what @vlaz said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! This can all be done succinctly with three concepts. Maps, destructuring and Object Shorthand notation (all three available in ES2015/6 as well as coffeescript)

```
options = []
ids = []

# We need to aggregate id's and options first
for {option_value_id, option} in op
  ids.push option_value_id
  options.push option

# Map through to the new Object
items = op.map ({ product_id, model, product}) ->
  {
    product_id
    model
    options: options
    product
    option_value_ids: ids
    quantity: 1
  }
```

Array.map will take an array and transform each element (in this case a subset of the bigger object) and return a new Array.  We will destructure the incoming object in the arguments and then shorthand them back into an object format.

[Array Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

[Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

[Shorthand Notation](https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand)

Comment: you're awesome!

Comment: Thanks glad to be of help!